ESLint config .mjs: TypeScript rules working, but plugins not applying
I've migrated my ESLint config to eslint.config.mjs and am trying to combine TypeScript and plugin rules:
import html from "eslint-plugin-html";
import tslint from "typescript-eslint";
import react from "eslint-plugin-react";
import jestdom from "eslint-plugin-jest-dom";

export default [
  ...tslint.configs.strict,
  ...tslint.configs.stylistic,
  {
    plugins: {
      html,
      jesdom,
      react
    },
    rules: {
      // ... custom rules
    }
  }
]

TypeScript rules are being applied correctly, but the plugins aren't detecting any issues. I've tried various configurations for the plugins, but nothing seems to work.
How can I correctly set up multiple configurations with plugins in an eslint.config.mjs file?

Can you share full config? are you actually using any rules from those plugins? Also, try @eslint/config-inspector

I didn't add it to the rules, I want to use the react.configs.recommended, how can I do it?

same way you use configs from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin. You need to learn to read documentation for stuff you use - it can be a lot to read, but it will save you a lot of time in a long run.

It works now, the inspector you suggested helped, thanks.
